# Wierd null characters when writing to a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was writing a function that replaces a single line in a text file to a user inputted one.

```
def file_redact(file_name: str):
    line_to_replace = int(input('Enter the line to replace (starting from 1): '))
    f = open(file_name, 'r+')
    file_data = f.readlines()
    file_data[line_to_replace - 1] = input('Write a new line:\n') + '\n'
    f.truncate(0)
    f.writelines(file_data)
    f.close()
```

The function does this just fine, however, it also adds null characters to the beginning of the file.

This is how the file looks like after I've replaced the first line:

```
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00Replaced text

Sample text2

Sample text3

Sample text4

Sample text5
```

Any help is appreciated, especially if there's a better way to implement this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstood what `file.truncate` does. It resizes the file, and obviously fills it with zero bytes or something. What you want is `file.seek`, which seeks the current write and read position to the given number. Alone, this could give problems when the replacement line is shorter than the original one, so you should use both `file.seek` and `file.truncate`. This code works:

```py
def file_redact(file_name: str):
    line_to_replace = int(input('Enter the line to replace (starting from 1): '))
    f = open(file_name, 'r+')
    file_data = f.readlines()
    file_data[line_to_replace - 1] = input('Write a new line:\n') + '\n'
    f.truncate(0)
    f.seek(0)
    f.writelines(file_data)
    f.close()
file_redact("test.txt")
```

Comment: You'll have a problem if the replacement line is shorter than the original.

Comment: The docs for `truncate` are not very clear, but I *think* it doesn't change the current file position.  So when he immediately calls `writelines`, those lines are written starting from the middle of the file instead of the beginning (and presumably the bytes up to that point are nulled out).

Comment: To fix @ScottHunter's point, I think you need a combination of `truncate` and `seek`.

Comment: @ScottHunter then maybe a combination of `seek` and `truncate` would be good ?

Answer (score 1):

It would be more straight-forward to open the file for reading (`'r'` mode) to read it and then re-open it for writing (`'w'` mode) to write to it.

Answer (score -3):

Try removing the `"\n"` from the input line:

```py
file_data[line_to_replace - 1] = input('Write a new line: )
```

Comment: If I understand right, the last `\n` writes empty line to the output line

Comment: You _did_ understand right, but removing the newline probably wont remove the null characters (whatever they are).

Comment: I just tested it, and as I expected it, it doesn't help. The null bytes are still showing up.

Comment: What do you mean by the `f.truncate(0)`?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean ?